# Gwt perfomance due to converting in to Java script

Tags: gwt

Hi i am using GWT after i came to know that GWT will convert in to javascript .

Then what about the performance issue ?? is it slower than a pure javascript application ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The code written in Java is converted by GWT compiler into javascript before you deploy your application. The compilation does not happen at run time.
2. GWT does optimization for the compiled javascript. It actually generates different versions for different browser and language combinations. It retrieves the appropriate javascript file for a browser using deferred binding. Also, it does obfuscation so that the compiled javascript size will be small.  So the your javascript application will be relatively faster.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually slower but the problem arises when you have a larger application so the size of your javascript file is getting larger and larger.

In the company where I am working we have over 1 MB JS file that has to be loaded during application start. We even had 2.5 MB before but we cut it with the use of code splitting (you can separate JS into more files but it's really not perfect).

But aside from this, GWT is really fast framework so don't worry about it. You can't also compare it to pure JS because GWT usually heavily communicates with server.